# Is there a way to setup TensorFlow RL training with a client via httprequests (or equivalent)?

Tags: tensorflow, http

Situation:

I have an Environment I can not directly control. I can, however, hook into that Environment and call httprequests from it. Using Post/Get requests I'd like to send current status data and retrieve the most probable next action to take. I'd like to do this for at least 1 client, but could use more. Desired Learning Method would be reinforcement learning (so I'd send reward with the Post request along the state).

I have seen similar behaviour in Unity's Implementation of TensorFlow, where it'll spawn multiple instances of your client to train the AI.

Answer (score 0):

OpenAI's [Gym](https://gym.openai.com/) environment is a very popular tool for training and visualizing reinforcement learnings problems. If your environment doesn't already exist in Gym, you can [make your own](https://medium.com/@apoddar573/making-your-own-custom-environment-in-gym-c3b65ff8cdaa). The basic structure of learning in gym is as follows:

1. Start in an initial state `s`
2. Send an HTTP request to the server with state information. Wait for the server to send a response containing an action.
3. Your agent executes this action and interacts with your environment and ends up in a new state `s'` and yields a reward `r`.
4. Send an HTTP request to the server with the reward `r` so that you may update your policy.

In your server, you want to write a request handler that accepts the state information `s`, computes a next action and sends this request back.

In terms of selection an action from your policy. You could use [Q-Learning](https://www.learndatasci.com/tutorials/reinforcement-q-learning-scratch-python-openai-gym/), which stores the value of taking an action in a state, and you select actions using an epsilon-greedy approach. You could also implement a neural network where your input would be your state vector, and your output would be a probability distribution over your possible actions. This is known as a [policy gradient method](https://medium.com/@thechrisyoon/deriving-policy-gradients-and-implementing-reinforce-f887949bd63).

Once you receive a reward, you can use this to improve your policy. This will be trickier with the policy gradient method which will require you to send a vector with gradient information to leverage automatic backpropagation tools.

Note that this method of selecting actions is incredibly slow for training. It would likely be best to train locally and perhaps use a server when deploying the agent if necessary.